# Handle schema references on mongoose

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, foreign-keys

I'm trying to define a simple RESTful API using Node.js, mongoose and restify. The goal is to have users which can comment on profiles of others users. For this I have a comment endpoint that receives a text, the author and the target of the comment (other user).

I want to reference users so I defined next schemas:

User schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  "username": { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  "password": { type: String, required: true },
  "comments": [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  text: { type: String, required: true },
  author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
  target: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true }
});

mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

I also have this controller (just showing createComment function):

```
exports.createComment = function(req, res, next) {
  var authorId, targetId;

  User.findOne({ _id: req.params.authorId}, function(err, author) {
    if (author) {
      User.findOne({ _id: req.params.targetId}, function(err, target) {
        if (target) {
          var comment = new Comment();
          comment.text = req.params.text;
          comment.author = author._id;
          comment.target = target._id;

          comment.save(function(err, comment) {
            if (err) {
              res.status(500);
              res.json({
                type: false,
                data: 'Error occurred: ' + err
              });
            } else {
              res.json({
                type: true,
                data: comment
              });
            }
          });
        } else {
          res.json({
            type: false,
            data: 'User ' + req.params.authorId + ' not found'
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.json({
        type: false,
        data: 'User ' + req.params.targetId + ' not found'
      });
    }
  });
};
```

So, I have three questions:

- Why do I need to check if the user received exists? I would like to receive only the id and store it but I have to do two more queries to check it myself.
- What I have to do to store in User only comments where that user is the target? **solved in the edited code**
- How can I simplify this code? Is a pain to have async queries executed in order. I would like to have generic errors and not to have to handle each one.

**EDIT**: I've simplified the code using validations on the schema:

Comment schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = mongoose.model('User');

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  text: { type: String, required: true },
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
  target: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true }
});

CommentSchema.path('author').validate(function(value, respond) {
  User.findOne({ _id: value}, function(err, user) {
    respond(!err && user);
  });
}, 'Author doesn\'t exists');

CommentSchema.path('target').validate(function(value, respond) {
  User.findOne({ _id: value}, function(err, user) {
    respond(!err && user);
  });
}, 'Target user doesn\'t exists');

mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

Controller:

```
exports.createComment = function(req, res, next) {
  var comment = new Comment(req.body);

  comment.save(function(err, comment) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500);
      res.json({
        type: false,
        data: 'Error occurred: ' + err
      });
    } else {
      User.findOne({ _id: comment.target }, function(err, user) {
        user.comments.push(comment);
        user.save();
      });

      res.json({
        type: true,
        data: comment
      });
    }
  });
};
```

The problem with this is that now I have to use _id on queries (I would like to use a custom id) and I'm doing three queries every time I want save a comment (2 for validation and one more to store the comment). Is there a better way to to this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the `select` option of query in mongo to select only the _id field of the user, like this:

   `User.findOne({_id:req.params.authorId}).select({_id:1}).exec(function(err,user) {})`
2. After you pull the userTarget from mongo, you need to add the comment._id to his list of comments, and save him:
   `target.comments.push(comment._id);
    target.save(function(err, targetAfterSaved) {})`
3. read about [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), they are my favorites Libraries to handle with async functions. For handle with errors like you want, you can add some listeners - [here](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#error-handling) is the documentation from restify site.

Hope you understand, if you need any help let me know